# get input value (react-testing library)

Tags: typescript, react-testing-library

Can't seem to get the value of an input using react-testing library, but for some reason one can set a value via `fireEvent`. `nameInput` is an actual input element

```
test('verify name validation works', () => {
    const { getByPlaceholderText, getByTestId, debug } = render(<Home/>)

    const passForm = getByTestId('form')
    const nameInput = getByPlaceholderText('Name');

    fireEvent.change(nameInput, { target: { value: 'TestName' }});
    debug(nameInput.value) // error
})
```

**Update**

I have to assert as `HTMLInputElement` to work as ts inferring it as a generic `HTMLElement`

`expect((nameInput as HTMLInputElement).value)`

Comment: Is it a controlled `input` ? otherwise the `change` will not really update the input value.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli it does update the input value, my problem is - I'm not able to get the value from the input

Comment: @swoopy To clarify, is your update the solution to your problem? Or are you still having an issue?

Comment: I'd suggest you add the update as an answer to this question then. Makes it clear for people landing here that the issue already has a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using type assertion, you can use generic:

```js
const nameInput = getByPlaceholderText<HTMLInputElement>('Name');
expect(nameInput.value).toBe('Nice!')
```

Answer (score 3):

I have to assert `nameInput` as `HTMLInputElement` to work as ts is inferring it as a generic `HTMLElement`

`expect((nameInput as HTMLInputElement).value)`

Comment: A solution without a type assertion would be nice. Type assertions can be dangerous.